# Is it possible to have reply-to field set to cc with nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, email

In nodemailer, when sending mail there is a message object with various parameters such as `from:`, `to:`, `subject:`, and `replyTo:`. The email address given in the replytTo field is the email address which any direct reply to the email will be addressed to. Is it possible to have a second email address which will automatically be the CC recipient of this reply email?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CC field for NodeMailer message object (https://nodemailer.com/message/), however this will not ensure that a user will CC the additional email address, as it would require the user to reply all rather than just reply.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, do you happen to know if there is such a thing as a replyToCC field? I guess it might just not exist.

Comment: No worries, as far as I can tell there is no such field.

Answer (score 0):

In current version (6.9.1) it seems to work passing it as `replyTo` property.

That being said, I couldn't find it documented anywhere and I also experienced some trouble while trying to achieve it.

For that reason I tried using `headers` to explicitly add 'Reply-To:' header, but this way it didn't work (when you try to reply, "to:" appears empty) at least for me (received in thunderbird across Exchange). Looking at received source, the only difference I could see from a working one was that, this way, 'Reply-To:' header appears **before** the "To:" one.

Tinkering with plugin implementation I finally discovered it actually works just with `replyTo`. At least taking care to put it **after** the `to` in *nodemailer* properties object.

If I try to put it before again (in properties, not using `headers`), received email source looks correct but does not work properly to me.

I guess there's some problem involving Exchange as mail server when "Reply-To:" comes before "To:" but I'm not fully sure of it (and won't spend more time in this...).

All I can say is that, to me, in Nodemailer 6.9.1, it works if just `replyTo` comes after `to` in properties object.

Hope it could help...